# Use a comparison test to examine the convergence of $\sum _{{k=2}}^{\infty }\frac{1}{(\ln k)^9}$

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence

> Use a comparison test to examine the convergence of $\sum _{{k=2}}^{\infty }\frac{1}{(\ln k)^9}$

I know that $\ln k < k$ and then $\frac{1}{\ln k} > \frac 1k$ 
But how can i do with $(\ln k) ^9$?

Comment: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that eventually $(\ln N)^9 < N$ for some big enough $N$. So then then we will have that $\frac{1}{(\ln N )^9} > \frac 1N$. So by direct comparison test, as $\sum_{k=N}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(\ln k )^9}$ diverges. Adding the finitely many terms before $\sum_{k=2}^{N-1} \frac{1}{(\ln k )^9}$ won't affect the convergence/divergence of the series.

It's fairly easy to notice that $N=10^{18}$ is a nice candidate, although we have that $\sqrt[9]{N} > \ln N$ for much smaller numbers.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a direct comparison test:

- Start with $\ln x < x$ for all $x > 0$.
- This means $9 \ln x < 9 x$ for all $x > 0$.
- This means $\ln x^9 < 9 x$ for all $x > 0$.
- Substitute $y = x^9$ we get 
  $$ \ln y < 9 y^{1/9} $$
  for every $y > 0$.
- So $(\ln y)^9 < 9^9 y$.

This tells us that 
$$ \frac{1}{(\ln n)^9} > \frac{1}{9^9} \frac{1}{n} $$
for every $n \geq 2$, so we can use the comparison test directly.